# What does server throughput mean

Tags: throughput

If the throughput is increase how will be changed the response and request time?
If I have the data(request/min)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JMeter's definition of throughput can be seen here: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html

Basically its a measure of how many requests that JMeter were able to send to your test site/application in one second. Or in another word the number of requests that your test site/application was able to receive from JMeter in one second. An increase in the throughput will mean your site/application was able to receive more requests per second while a decrease will mean a reduction in the number of request it handled per second.

The relationship between throughput with response/request time totally depends as ysth stated. I typically use this number to see the load of the server but run the test several times (30x min) and take the average.

Answer (score 0):

After completing the project development as developers, we are responsible for testing the application's performance.
As part of performance testing, we have to check:

1. Response time of the application
2. Bottleneck of the application
3. Throughput of the application

##### Throughput of application:

In general, 'Request capacity of application in a given time.'

As per [Apache JMeter doc](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

> Throughput is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
> The formula is: Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).